# Converting stack structure of double to type void*

Tags: c, stack

I've got a program, that has a few libraries written for it already. The structure stackElementT was a double, now it needs to be converted to a type of void pointer. I understand I need to allocate memory for each time I push a number into the stack, but cannot figure out what to allocate for. if I only convert the structure to a type of void* then i get the following errors:

```
gcc -I../booklib  -c rpncalc.c
In file included from rpncalc.c:14:0:
stack.h:65:41: warning: parameter 2 (‘element’) has void type [enabled by default]
void Push(stackADT stack, stackElementT element);
                                     ^
rpncalc.c: In function ‘main’:
rpncalc.c:44:17: error: type of formal parameter 2 is incomplete
             Push(operandStack, StringToReal(line));
             ^
rpncalc.c: In function ‘ApplyOperator’:
rpncalc.c:69:9: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
 rhs = Pop(operandStack);
     ^
rpncalc.c:70:9: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
 lhs = Pop(operandStack);
     ^
rpncalc.c:79:12: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘double’ from type ‘void *’
 result = malloc(result * sizeof(double *));
        ^
rpncalc.c:80:5: error: type of formal parameter 2 is incomplete
 Push(operandStack, result);
 ^
rpncalc.c: In function ‘DisplayStack’:
rpncalc.c:135:13: error: invalid use of void expression
         printf("%g", GetStackElement(stack, i));
         ^
make: *** [rpncalc.o] Error 1
```

here is the stack.h code:

```
/*
 * File: stack.h
 * -------------
 * This interface defines an abstraction for stacks.  In any
 * single application that uses this interface, the values in
 * the stack are constrained to a single type, although it
 * is easy to change that type by changing the definition of
 * stackElementT in this interface.
 */

#ifndef _stack_h
#define _stack_h

#include "genlib.h"

/*
 * Type: stackElementT
 * -------------------
 * The type stackElementT is used in this interface to indicate
 * the type of values that can be stored in the stack.  Here the
 * stack is used to store values of type double, but that can
 * be changed by editing this definition line.
 */

typedef void stackElementT;

/*
 * Type: stackADT
 * --------------
 * The type stackADT represents the abstract type used to store
 * the elements that have been pushed.  Because stackADT is
 * defined only as a pointer to a concrete structure that is not
 * itself defined in the interface, clients have no access to
 * the underlying fields.
 */

typedef struct stackCDT *stackADT;

/*
 * Function: NewStack
 * Usage: stack = NewStack();
 * --------------------------
 * This function allocates and returns a new stack, which is
 * initially empty.
 */

stackADT NewStack(void);

/*
 * Function: FreeStack
 * Usage: FreeStack(stack);
 * ------------------------
 * This function frees the storage associated with the stack.
 */

void FreeStack(stackADT stack);

/*
 * Function: Push
 * Usage: Push(stack, element);
 * ----------------------------
 * This function pushes the specified element onto the stack.
 */

void Push(stackADT stack, stackElementT element);

/*
 * Function: Pop
 * Usage: element = Pop(stack);
 * ----------------------------
 * This function pops the top element from the stack and returns
 * that value.  The first value popped is always the last one
 * that was pushed.  If the stack is empty when Pop is called,
 * the function calls Error with an appropriate message.
 */

stackElementT Pop(stackADT stack);

/*
 * Functions: StackIsEmpty, StackIsFull
 * Usage: if (StackIsEmpty(stack)) . . .
 *        if (StackIsFull(stack)) . . .
 * -------------------------------------
 * This functions test whether the stack is empty or full.
 */

bool StackIsEmpty(stackADT stack);
bool StackIsFull(stackADT stack);

/*
 * Function: StackDepth
 * Usage: depth = StackDepth(stack);
 * ---------------------------------
 * This function returns the number of elements currently pushed
 * on the stack.
 */

int StackDepth(stackADT stack);

/*
 * Function: GetStackElement
 * Usage: element = GetStackElement(stack, index);
 * -----------------------------------------------
 * This function returns the element at the specified index in
 * the stack, where the top of the stack is defined as index 0.
 * For example, calling GetStackElement(stack, 0) returns the top
 * element on the stack without removing it.  If the caller tries
 * to select an out-of-range element, GetStackElement calls Error.
 * Note: This function is not a fundamental stack operation and
 * is instead provided principally to facilitate debugging.
 */

stackElementT GetStackElement(stackADT stack, int index);

#endif
```

and here is the rpncalc.c which does the pushing and poping:

```
/*
 * File: rpncalc.c
 * ---------------
 * This program simulates an electronic calculator that uses
 * reverse Polish notation, in which the operators come after
 * the operands to which they apply.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "genlib.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "strlib.h"
#include "stack.h"

/* Private function prototypes */

static void ApplyOperator(char op, stackADT operandStack);
static void HelpCommand(void);
static void ClearStack(stackADT operandStack);
static void DisplayStack(stackADT operandStack);

/* Main program */

main()
{
    stackADT operandStack;
    string line;
    char ch;

    printf("RPN Calculator Simulation (type H for help)\n");
    operandStack = NewStack();
    while (TRUE) {
        line = malloc(line * sizeof(double *));
        printf("> ");
        line = GetLine();
        ch = toupper(line[0]);
        switch (ch) {
          case 'Q': exit(0);
          case 'H': HelpCommand(); break;
          case 'C': ClearStack(operandStack); break;
          case 'S': DisplayStack(operandStack); break;
          default:
            if (isdigit(ch)) {
                Push(operandStack, StringToReal(line));
            } else {
                ApplyOperator(ch, operandStack);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

/* Private functions */

/*
 * Function: ApplyOperator
 * Usage: ApplyOperator(op, operandStack);
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This function applies the operator to the top two elements on
 * the operand stack.  Because the elements on the stack are
 * popped in reverse order, the right operand is popped before
 * the left operand.
 */

static void ApplyOperator(char op, stackADT operandStack)
{
    double lhs, rhs, result;

    rhs = Pop(operandStack);
    lhs = Pop(operandStack);
    switch (op) {
      case '+': result = lhs + rhs; break;
      case '-': result = lhs - rhs; break;
      case '*': result = lhs * rhs; break;
      case '/': result = lhs / rhs; break;
      default:  Error("Illegal operator %c", op);
    }
    printf("%g\n", result);
    result = malloc(result * sizeof(double *));
    Push(operandStack, result);
}

/*
 * Function: HelpCommand
 * Usage: HelpCommand();
 * ---------------------
 * This function generates a help message for the user.
 */

static void HelpCommand(void)
{
    printf("Enter expressions in Reverse Polish Notation,\n");
    printf("in which operators follow the operands to which\n");
    printf("they apply.  Each line consists of a number, an\n");
    printf("operator, or one of the following commands:\n");
    printf("  Q -- Quit the program\n");
    printf("  H -- Display this help message\n");
    printf("  C -- Clear the calculator stack\n");
    printf("  S -- Display all values in the stack\n");
}

/*
 * Function: ClearStack
 * Usage: ClearStack(stack);
 * -------------------------
 * This function clears the stack by popping elements until it is
 * empty.
 */

static void ClearStack(stackADT stack)
{
    while (!StackIsEmpty(stack)) {
        (void) Pop(stack);
    }
}

/*
 * Function: DisplayStack
 * Usage: DisplayStack(stack);
 * ---------------------------
 * This function displays the contents of a stack.
 */

static void DisplayStack(stackADT stack)
{
    int i, depth;

    printf("Stack: ");
    depth = StackDepth(stack);
    if (depth == 0) {
        printf("empty\n");
    } else {
        for (i = depth - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (i < depth - 1) printf(", ");
            printf("%g", GetStackElement(stack, i));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: "now it needs to be converted to a type of void pointer". So `typedef void stackElementT;` is supposed to be `typedef void *stackElementT;`

Answer (score 0):

"but cannot figure out what to allocate for"

The solution is quite simple: inside your structure you must have your void pointer which is used to store a pointer to a memory space destinated for the type you want (you get to choose the type of every item). For the function Push, you must pass as argument to Push the value you want to work with (e.g. double). Lets pretend that you have

```
void *item;
```

defined as a pointer to void in your structure. All you have to do is allocate dynamic memory for double, and make a copy of the value passed as argument to your structure. Like this:

```
stack->item = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)); //the void pointer variable now stores the address to a memory location for double variable
*(stack->item) = value;
```

Allocating is as simple as that: the user of your library doesn't need to know how the generic stack is implemented.

If you want to store a pointer, you do the same thing but there's no need to make a copy. The pointer to this structure you want in your stack can be directly assigned to item:

```
stack->item = argument; //argument is a pointer to a structure (e.g. FILE).
```

Also, in your freeing stack function, you must remember to free the pointers to the values you're storing. It all works like that, and remember to typecast in malloc, like I did. When you assign a pointer to void* variable, you must cast the type of that pointer.